# XML and Jquery Mobile xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to treverse through [an XML file](http://crmmobile.eyepax.info/xmlResponce.xml) using jquery mobile.

My code goes as below

```
testsss = $(xmlHttpRequest).find("/NewDataSet/Table[1]/OrganizationID/").text();
```

but I'm always getting an **empty** string. Can someone help me out??

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Could you add a http://jsfiddle.net with an example?

Comment: phill I figured it out. please see my answer below. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(xmlHttpRequest).find("Table OrganizationName:eq(2)").text();
```

did the magic